# Errors when unit testing nestjs

Tags: testing, nestjs

When unit testing the nestjs file:
yandex-ndd-api-client.controller.spec.ts
there are errors like this (many):

```
  Cannot find module 'src/sync.service' from 'yandex-ndd-api-client/yandex-ndd-api-client.controller.spec.ts'
```

I'm trying to change to a relative path:

```
import { SyncService } from './../../src/sync.service';
```

In the test file itself, it stops swearing, but when I do the same in the project files, the project itself gives an error when launched:

```
Error: Cannot find module './../../src/sync.service'
```

In tsconfig.json:
"baseUrl": "./",

How to make friends tests with the application?

Comment: add `sync.service` in the modules provider array

Comment: What's the file structure look like?